# LaTex Summary Table Options for Zelig MLogit Results

Tags: r, latex, r-zelig, texreg

I've been trying to extract my summary stats from an `mlogit` model run through `Zelig` using `texreg`, `stargazer` and `memisc`.

`texreg` throws me the following error:

```
texreg(MLogitRes3)
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : unable to find an     
inherited method for function ‘extract’ for signature ‘"vglm"’
```

`stargazer` throws me the following error:

```
stargazer(MLogitRes3)
Error in objects[[i]]$zelig.call : 
$ operator not defined for this S4 class
```

`memisc` (using the `mtable` function) throws me this final error:

```
mtable(MLogitRes3)
Error in UseMethod("getSummary") : 
no applicable method for 'getSummary' applied to an object of class
"c('vglm',  'vlm', 'vlmsmall')"
```

Do none of these packages support `mlogit` choice models within `zelig`? Do I have options to export my summary stats into a table usable in LaTex elsewhere?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to reproduce this recently? I just checked out the code for `texreg::extract.zelig` and it appears to have a method for `mlogit`:

```
function (model, include.aic = TRUE, include.bic = TRUE, include.loglik = TRUE, 
    include.deviance = TRUE, include.nobs = TRUE, include.rsquared = TRUE, 
    include.adjrs = TRUE, include.fstatistic = TRUE, ...) 
    ...
    else if ("mlogit" %in% class(model)) {
        coefficient.names <- rownames(s@coef3)
        coefficients <- s@coef3[, 1]
        standard.errors <- s@coef3[, 2]
        zval <- s@coef3[, 3]
        significance <- 2 * pnorm(abs(zval), lower.tail = FALSE)
        gof <- numeric()
        gof.names <- character()
        gof.decimal <- logical()
        if (include.loglik == TRUE) {
            lik <- logLik(model)[1]
            gof <- c(gof, lik)
            gof.names <- c(gof.names, "Log Likelihood")
            gof.decimal <- c(gof.decimal, TRUE)
        }
        if (include.deviance == TRUE) {
            dev <- deviance(s)
            if (!is.null(dev)) {
                gof <- c(gof, dev)
                gof.names <- c(gof.names, "Deviance")
                gof.decimal <- c(gof.decimal, TRUE)
            }
        }
        if (include.nobs == TRUE) {
            n <- nrow(model$data)
            gof <- c(gof, n)
            gof.names <- c(gof.names, "Num. obs.")
            gof.decimal <- c(gof.decimal, FALSE)
        }
        tr <- createTexreg(coef.names = coefficient.names, coef = coefficients, 
            se = standard.errors, pvalues = significance, gof.names = gof.names, 
            gof = gof, gof.decimal = gof.decimal)
        return(tr)
    }
    ...
}
```

Anyway, if you're still having trouble, you may want to read [Section 6 of the `texreg` article](https://cran.gis-lab.info/web/packages/texreg/vignettes/v55i08.pdf) which gives you instructions for how to define your own `extract` method for any model, and/or write the package author (Philip Leifeld) to get support added.